# Editing cmd commands to use python

Tags: python, bash, cmd

Suppose that I have a Python file named

```sh
test.py
```

and I want to be able to run it with different versions of python installed in my computer.
I know this can be done for example:

To run it with my version of Python2.x:

```sh
py -2 test.py
```

To run it with my version of Python3.x:

```sh
py -3 test.py
```

I would like to edit the way this command is written, in order to:
Use Python2.x with

```sh
python2 test.py
```

Use Python3.x with

```sh
python3 test.py
```

I guess I have to edit some system variables, but I am not quite sure which and I don't want to mess up anything. I am using Windows10. Anybody has any idea?

Comment: There are a number of ways to do that, none of them will be *Windows native*. The `py` launcher was invented in Windows for a reason. If you want to go that way, you will have to  create a `python2.bat` and `python3.bat` files that in turn will call the proper interpretor *and pass it the command line*. And that part will cause headaches if you have to use *complex* parameters containing quotation marks... The only reliable way would be to use lew level (C) programs that directly ask Windows for the exact command line through the `GetCommandLine` API function.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your script by specifying the path for your specific python version like so: `c:\python\2.5\python.exe test.py`.

You can also create environment variables for each version manually if you'd like to. [Create and modify environment variables Windows 10](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/r-enterprise/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html#GUID-DD6F9982-60D5-48F6-8270-A27EC53807D0)